# Get the UserName of the authenticated (confirmed) user on Lambda?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, amazon-cognito

After the account, which is signed up in Mobile app, verified, i want Lambda function to receive UserID. Due to this reason, i have created POST API in API Gateway. "Invoke with caller credentials" is checked, and Body Mapping Template was added as

```
{ "identity": "$input.params('identity')" }
```

Unfortunately, when i have tested it in API Gateway, it gives HTTP Error 404-Not Found Error.

```
print context.identity
```

resulted as

```
<_main__.CognitoIdentity object at 0x7eg6f79v2bed2>
```

&

```
print context.identity.cognito_identity_id
```

resulted as

```
None
```

Even, when i have tried from Mobile app, only after i have entered the verification number, HTTP Error 404-Not Found alert is seen in the screen.
I have given all permissions as AWSLambdaFullAccess Policy and AmazonAPIGatewayInvokeFullAccess Policy, to Cognito (Auth and UnAuth) IAM Roles.
 I will be glad if you let me know about the solution of issue.

[Lamda Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sHFUz.jpg), [API Gateway PUSH API Seetings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dmh0C.jpg), [API Gateway PUSH API Method](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2acX3.jpg)

Comment: try to use { "sub": "$context.authorizer.claims.sub" }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have an authenticated user then that means you have access token for that authentication passed to lambda,

With `Access Token` you can obtain user information and its attributes.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/CognitoIdentityServiceProvider.html#getUser-property

```
var params = {
  AccessToken: 'STRING_VALUE' /* required */
};
cognitoidentityserviceprovider.getUser(params, function(err, data) {
  if (err) console.log(err, err.stack); // an error occurred
  else     console.log(data);           // successful response
});
```

This code is good in node or javascript.

If you are using other SDK's it will have similar signature.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response Kannaiyan, i want to learn that after validation (confirmed) of signUp stage of user in app, how i can push access token to Lambda automatically only for that user. Finally i do not need all the user IDs registered before or to call them by their access tokens, i only need the userID who is registered in that moment. Instead of calling ID with access token, this info should be pushed to Lambda (over API Gateway or else), i am beginner in aws services, i will be glad if you can let me know about the solution. Kind regards...

Comment: i am planning to use same method (get_user) in python in following code, response = client.get_user(AccessToken='string'). How i can pass Access Token from Cognito to Lambda function. In get_User method, its mentioned that “The access token returned by the server response to get information about the user”. How I can implement it? After user is confirmed(verified), this access token should pass to lambda function. (Note: my lambda function is triggered from Cognito-Post Confirmation)

Answer (score 3):

If you use COGNITO_USER_POOLS for the Authorization on that endpoint then you can set the 'Authorization' header as the idToken in the post request. API gateway then verifies the token and passes it through to the function.

Then in your lambda function you should be able to access the Cognito user object like this.

```
const cognitoUser = event.requestContext.authorizer.claims;
```

I prefer this to the @Kannaiyan's answer because you don't have to make another call to get the user data.

Comment: I have used IAM authorisation and this field doesnot exist